# Open Source .Net Web Registration Form Generator

Tags: asp.net, forms, open-source, webforms

Anybody know of / have experience with .net web registration form generator, that is free and/or open source?

Something like a very simple version of InfoPath web forms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> [AspxFormsGen 3.5](http://www.junnark.com/AspxFormsGen.aspx) is a tool that
>   automatically generates (ASP.Net 3.5
>   Generator) ASP.Net 3.5 Standard
>   WebForms (.aspx) in C# 3.5 or VB 9.0
>   and their accompanying CodeFile
>   (.aspx.cs or .aspx.vb). It generates
>   WebForms with CRUD (Create, Retrieve,
>   Update, Delete) functionalities using
>   the latest Linq-to-SQL and
>   LinqDataSource, based on the tables in
>   your MS SQL 2000/2005 Database, all in
>   One Click. [Download](http://download.cnet.com/Free-AspxFormsGen-3-5-Exp-Asp-Net-3-5-Generator/3000-10248_4-10548350.html).

There are some good open source web-based Content Management Systems that has customizable profiling and excellent community contributed modules for free. Some of them are:

- [Umbraco](http://umbraco.org) (Recommended)
- [Dotnetnuke](http://dotnetnuke.com)